# Site Url missing from password reset url in email

Tags: email, password

Password reset email does not include `http://www.mywebsite.com` in url.

It's only showing this: `/manage.php?D=cp&C=login&M=reset_password&id=2AJKS6Rs`

Per other forums with related issues, I've changed site index in config, removed .htaccess, but with no luck.

Any idea what the issue is and how to resolve? Thanks in advance.

Comment: EE Version? Do you have any email modules installed, or any other add-on that might be using extensions hooks related to email?

Comment: I believe it's 2.5.3. I have "Email", User Email Module installed...think that's an out of the box module if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: What does "Admin > General Configuration > URL to the root directory of your site"  say?

Comment: Shows a full url, `http://www.mywebsite.com/`